# Queuing mail with attachData in Laravel 5.1 / OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, octobercms

The following ***IS*** working when I use `Mail::send`

```
$email = 'my@email.com';
$name = 'My Name';
$invoice = InvoicePdf::generate($invoice_id); // generates PDF as raw data

Mail::send('mail.template', null, function($message) use ($name, $email, $invoice) {

    $message->to($email, $name);
    $message->subject('Thank you for your order!');
    $message->attachData($invoicePdf, 'invoice.pdf', ['mime' => 'application/pdf']);

});
```

It works fine and an email is generated with the correct PDF attachment.

However, if I change `Mail::send` to `Mail::queue` then I receive the following error:

> `Unable to JSON encode payload. Error code: 5`
>
> `/var/www/html/october/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Queue.php
>   line 90`

If I take the `$message->attachData();` line out then it works even with `Mail::queue` so it seems like the raw data from the attachment is causing issues with the queue but there's nothing in the relevant [October](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/mail) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail) docs about how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be its because `$invoicePdf` data is raw data of `PDF file` and php can not process that data (`attachData`) when saving to database.

> hmm, alternative you can generate file and then just attach `file path` to mail and then add to queue.

```
// generate tempfile name
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'inv');

// this pdf is generated by renatio plugin but you can 
// use your data and save it to disk
PDF::loadTemplate('renatio::invoice')
    ->save($temp_file);

Mail::queue('mail.template', null, function($message) use ($name, $email, $temp_file) {
    $message->to($email, $name);
    $message->subject('Thank you for your order!');
    $message->attach($temp_file, ['as' => 'Your_Invoice.pdf', 'mime' => 'application/pdf']);
});
```

it should work.

`@Joseph` pointed that in Laravel 5.5 there is `mailable` which can be used. `@Joseph` pointed this solution and it seems working so you can also use this solution if your `laravel` version is `>= 5.5`
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-email-with-a-pdf-attachment

Thanks @Joseph

Comment: Yes, saving it and then referencing saved file works but it's an extra step that I wanted to avoid. I was hoping that there would be a way to encode the raw data so that it could be added to the queue. If nobody can thi k of a solution then I will mark you answer as correct but hopefully there is another way.

Comment: I will also try to figure this out as well and update answer if i found nicer correct way.

Comment: I've found a better way to do it! I just remembered that the current version of OctoberCMS is actually using Laravel 5.5 and not 5.1 so I can use the new "Mailable" feature (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#writing-mailables) and follow the example by deselbi at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sending-email-with-a-pdf-attachment -- I'll figure out the best way to do it and then post a Q&A for it on SO and post a link to it in the comments here. I've marked your answer as correct though as I think it's probably the best way in Laravel 5.1!

Comment: cool, thanks added your link in answer so it will help others as well :)